# Get error while login with facebook button on those mobile in which facebook Lite is installed

Tags: java, android, facebook, kotlin, facebook-login

i'm getting error or those mobiles in which FB app is not installed or lite version is installed. i don't know how to handle call back so that when button is pressed and chrome opens it et back the information in app. app is working fine in mobiles having Facebook app in it. getting error or those mobiles in which FB app is not installed or lite version is installed.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var a: Int = 1
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager
    lateinit var dialog: ProgressDialog
    lateinit var credential: AuthCredential

    var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    val currentUsers = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
//    val currentUsers = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

//    var verification:FirebaseUser?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        dialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        dialog.setTitle("Welcome...")
        dialog.setMessage("Signing in. Please wait!")
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext())
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()


        printHashKey(this)
        // login_button.setReadPermissions("email")
        login_button.setOnClickListener {

            signIn()
            //facebookLogin()

        }

        signup_btn.setOnClickListener {
            intent = Intent(this, SignupActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }


        forget_pas.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, forget_pass::class.java))
        }

        button.setOnClickListener {


            fun View.hideKeyboard() {
                val inputManager =
                    context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
            }

            it.hideKeyboard()

            if (mail.text.toString().isEmpty() || Tpassword.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter your Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                dialog.show()
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)

                doLogin()
            }

        }


    }

    //Login code
    private fun doLogin() {
        if (mail.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            mail.error = "Please enter email"
            mail.requestFocus()
            return
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail.text.toString()).matches()) {
            mail.error = "Please enter valid email"
            mail.requestFocus()
            return
        }

        if (Tpassword.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            Tpassword.error = "Please enter password"
            Tpassword.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        val user = auth.currentUser

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail.text.toString(), Tpassword.text.toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) { // && user!!.isEmailVerified

                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    Log.d("task.isSuccessful)", "task.isSuccessful)")

                    if (user!!.isEmailVerified) { // || currentUsers == null
                        startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))

                        Log.d("user isEmailVerified", "user isEmailVerified")
                        dialog.cancel()

                    }
//                    startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
//                    finish()
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please verify your Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        dialog.cancel()
                    }
                } else {

                    dialog.cancel()
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Error! Verify your email or Enter correct Password",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    return@addOnCompleteListener
                }
            }
    }

    //    public override fun onStart() {
    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // super.onStart()
//        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        // if(a==1){}
//        var currentUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


        updateUI(user)


    }

    private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {


        Log.d("update ui fun", "function of update ui")

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.reload()?.addOnSuccessListener { void ->
            //            var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


            if (currentUsers != null) {
                Log.d("facebook user not null", "updateUI")
//                Toast.makeText(this,"Inside of if",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//                finish()
                startActivity(Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java))
//                dialog.show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "do it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d("else", "else updateUI")
            }
        }

    }

    //fb code
    private fun signIn() { **below line is not working on FB LITE**
        login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(result?.accessToken)

            }

            override fun onCancel() {

            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                Log.d("fb", error.toString())
            }

        })
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)


    }

    //facebook code
    private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(accessToken: AccessToken?) {
        //Get Credentials

        credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken!!.token)

        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this)
            { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    //Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                    dialog.show()


//                    if (currentUsers != null) {
//                      Log.d("fb button"," currentUser!= null")
                    intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)

                    startActivity(intent)


// updateUI(user)

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()


                    //updateUI(null)
                }

//                }
            }

    }


    //forgot_password code
    fun forgotPassword(username: EditText) {
        if (username.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            return

        }
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(username.text.toString()).matches()) {
            return
        }

        auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(username.text.toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Email sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
            }
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        finishAffinity()
    }

    fun printHashKey(pContext: Context) {
        try {
            val info = pContext.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(pContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (i in info.signatures) {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(i.toByteArray())
                val hashKey = String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.i("hash", "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("hash", e.printStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please do focus on signIn functon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release key was the only solution for this problem which i got. Paste the release key in firebase where Hash key was pasted. Find out how to generate release key.